# HUD/UI freeze and stutter in Bioshock Infinite

Tags: pc, bioshock-infinite

I've played Bioshock Infinite for about 18 hours and started to notice some UI freezes in the game, that have made the game unplayable. The UI started to freeze as soon as I tried to loot some NPC or object. It doesn't show itself timely, the UI is half-transparent and doesn't react to keyboard inputs. The whole bug resulted in the game freezing as soon as I ALT+TABbed or opened the main menu of the game.

It is complicated to completely describe this bug in words, that's why I'll link [the video with the same effect here](https://youtu.be/fhD-wz8jtIs), that I've found on the Internet:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is really simple to fix - you just should turn the V-Sync ON in the game video settings.

Answer (score 0):

> you just should turn the V-Sync ON in the game video settings

More specifically:

```
Options -> Graphics -> Lock Framerate = ON
```

I had the same UI problem, and this setting fixed it for me. The dialog boxes now appear and disappear as expected.